# Rails javascript_tag output not executing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that I am developing and I have inserted a some javascript code into one of my views.

```
<% content_for :content do %>
    <div id="simulator-phone">
        <%= image_tag("iPhone5.png", :id => "iPhone5") %>
        <iframe id="simulator-screen"></iframe>
    </div>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#simulator-screen').load('/simulator/LZA');
        });
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the Javascript gets inserted into the output like this and therefor never executes...

```
<div id="simulator-phone">
    <img alt="Iphone5" id="iPhone5" src="/assets/iPhone5.png">
    <iframe id="simulator-screen"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $('#simulator-screen').load('/simulator/LZA');" 
    //]]>
</script>
```

What do I need to do to make it actually execute the javascript being passed.

**EDIT:**

Ok, now I fixed that, but the iframe is now not loading with the contents of `/simulator/LZA`. Thoughts?

Comment: Getting rid of the `iframe` will probably fix it. It starts after the `iframe` and doesn't seem to have to do anything with `javascript_tag`.

Comment: It looks like we're missing something here because, as pointed out by @Mischa, this starts with your attempted closing of the iframe with a `</div>` tag.

Comment: Oh crap! yeah, that's it. I changed the `<div>` to an `<iframe>` and apparently forgot to change the closing tag as well.

Comment: May I ask, why are you using jQuery here?, and not `src` directly I mean.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo It has been years since I've used iframes (Personally hate them) but it seems best for this particular application. I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be doing:

```
$('#simulator-screen').attr("src", '/simulator/LZA');

//or
$('#simulator-screen')[0].src = '/simulator/LZA';

//or, better yet
document.getElementById('simulator-screen').src = '/simulator/LZA';
```